# Mouse arrow moving on its own

Tags: mouse, touchpad

lately I've been having this weird problem. The mouse arrow would for no apparent reason, begin moving diagonally from the right of the screen to the bottom left. This happens regardless if I am using a mouse or the touchpad. Sometimes the way to stop it is to unplug the mouse (if one is attached), or wait for it to settle down at the bottom left corner of the screen. Trying to move the mouse arrow while it is going on it's little joy-ride feels like swimming against a tide. Its really annoying especially if I need to show my supervisor something and the arrow decides to act up..
A colleague has the exact same machine but with Xubuntu installed, and has never had this issue.

p.s. I'm running Unity 14.04 on a Toshiba Portege Z30a notebook.

Edit: output of xinput:

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: And also please add `dmesg | grep pnp` output.

Comment: Does this only happen when a USB optical mouse is plugged in?

Comment: Pilot6 - dmesg  | grep pnp does not produce an output

Comment: Wilf - nope. It also happens without a mouse.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your touchpad is not properly detected.
You can disable it by running

```
xinput disable 11
```

This should stop this problem, but you will not be able to use touchpad.

Comment: And what happens after the next reboot?

Comment: If this helps to solve the issue, I would add how to make it permanent.

Comment: This helped me with a similar issue (although I had to disable 12 and keep 11, because I think for me it was the nub between the g,h, and b of my keyboard versus the touchpad that appears to be generating spurious inputs); any thoughts on how to make it permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Restart touchpad's driver by running:

```
sudo  modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```